# Is sharding activated on Ethereum?

Tags: sharding

I had read somewhere that Ethereum 2.0 would have multiple shards. This means that the Ethereum blockchain would be divided into several "pieces." Do you know if, at this moment, this feature is present on Ethereum, or if it's a functionality planned for later ?

If yes, why don't we see on a blockchain explorer which shard a transaction occurred on ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ethereum does not have sharding (yet), beacuse Ethereum developers could never really figure it out. Instead, the current focus is on so-called rollup centric scaling or layer twos.

There is no timeline if Ethereum is going to have sharding, or ever. There are some roadmaps, but they are not very concrete, as they already diverted from the earlier roadmap that was still discussing about sharding.

However multiple blockchains are implementing sharding today

- MultiversX
- NEAR
- TON

[For more information about sharding, a good place to start is to refer to this NEAR blog post](https://medium.com/nearprotocol/near-launches-nightshade-sharding-phase-1-the-next-alpha-is-near-eafa108bc28c).

Comment: Vitalik Buterin is discovering the operation of a distributed computer the hard way. He would better grab a book and learn about distributed computing before doing any forks. But well, it is his money, he can do what he please.